# Show "Questions with similar titles" from other sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, similar-questions

When writing a new question, a very useful list *Questions with similar titles* appears. As far as I know this list contains titles from the site where you are at that moment. **Would it be feasible to extend this list with questions from other sites?**

The reason why I ask is that I recently got an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895806/how-to-implement-polymorphic-associations-in-an-existing-database) at Stack Overflow. The answer linked to dba.stackexchange.com. As database design is not my core business I had never noticed this site before. By the way, Stack Overflow's faq section on [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) does not (yet?) refer to it.

So cross-site "similar titles" either could have given me a spot-on duplicate (even an instant answer!) or otherwise have guided me to a more appropriate site for my question.

Maybe migration paths can be used to limit the number of sites to search through.

Related questions, but not the same:

- ["Questions with Similar Titles" Could Do Better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107258/questions-with-similar-titles-could-do-better)
- [Display other SE site links in the linked questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/also-display-other-se-site-links-as-linked-questions)
- [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

Comment: I am not sure if migration paths can be helpful; _Drupal Answers_ is not in the migration path for _Stack Overflow_, but there are some questions that are asked in both the sites.

Comment: you mean for example if some going to ask a question on programming about bitmap images to get similar questions about images from the photographers ?

Comment: Given the Gaming community's propensity to post [questions with absurd titles when taken out of context](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/7364), that site is probably going to come up on a *lot* of other sites for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Aristos. A programming question on images (_best way to store images in a database_) is not likely to get any hits at photographers. If it does, some question is misplaced.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn. That's a good point. Hard to tackle. Maybe there it could help to look at relates sites. Too bad though if there is a migration path to gaming.

Comment: @GertArnold If they never get this two connected (programming+photographer) then they should not be connected. So you speak for only two or three connection, programming with database and maybe code improve.

Comment: @Aristos And the four sites refered to in the faq. I'm trying to find a way to guide people to the best site for their questions. If so far it would only work for the programming-related sites, I'd be happy enough.

Comment: @GertArnold Then the way you say it I think of a better idea. A GLOBAL BOX of what ever question, and there this global question box (a google search style page for example) can locate all the possible topics around Sacks.

Comment: a global page similar to the print page, that can ask anything... and there maybe can suggest sites under that this question can fit... And a global site page for search all on stack ? hmmm google....

Comment: This sounds kind of similar to something I mentioned at the end of my question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117454/148400

Comment: @David. Funny that I did not find your question when I wrote mine. I spent quite some time searching. No need to mention that I like your approach there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This could be problematic for a number of reasons:

1. For "close as duplicate" purposes, there is no such thing as a cross-site duplicate.
2. Questions from other sites are asked in a different context.  There's no real expectation that such questions would have similar answers.
3. Queries like this would be extremely expensive; SE sites are not always on the same database server.

Comment: The last point is a real killer! Probably terminal. The other two points could be dealt with I think.

Comment: Can we ask for cross-site duplicates? I've wanted that vote-to-close before...

Comment: point 3 is really convincing, but on the other hand: maybe this could be done not for all stackexchange sites, but at least for those which have a significant overlap like superuser.se, stackoverflow.se, emacs.se, tex.se ...? There are a lot of questions which already do have related topics on one of the other sites